# Android emulator launch error

Tags: android, android-emulator

ProcessNotCreatedException:

> Error launching emulator: Cannot run program "C:\Users\UmeshKhanna\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

How do I fix this problem, and get the emulator to work again ?